# Sql 2005 Backups and Schema Changes Interactions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, schema, backup

I'm not clear about the interaction between database schema changes and differential backups on sql 2005.

Lets say I do a Full backup right right now.
Then I perform some schema changes.
Then I do a diff backup.

What happens?  Do I need to create another FULL backup?  Are my schema changes and any data in those new schema bits included in my diff backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

All changes, whether structural changes or data modifications, within the database (i.e. any object that resides within the database) since your last full database backup will be recorded by any subsequent differential backup that you execute.

I hope this clears things up for you but please feel free to pose further questions.

cheers, John

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all changes to the table will be kept in the differential backup.  This includes all DDL code that is executed against the database.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, a non-full backup (LOG or DIFF) includes all schema changes.

Remember: user tables, column, stored proc defs, indexes, the whole shebang are stored in tables that exist on disk in data pages just like your data...